# My "else" statement does not work. It keeps showing the "if" statement's alert even if it's below 14

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
  function buy() {

    let name = prompt("What is your name?");

    let age = prompt("How old are you?");

    if (age <= 14) {

        alert("Hey, " + name + "!  Have fun buying on our site! ");

    } else {

          alert("Sorry, " + name + "... You are too young to buy on our website. You might have to ask your parents. ");

    }

  }

  let buyButton = document.querySelector(".buy-button");

  buyButton.addEventListener("click", buy);
```

```html
<button class="buy-button">Buy Button</button>
```

Comment: `let age = +prompt("How old are you?");` — you have to convert it to a number.

Comment: Javascript and Java aren't the same language -- they're not even related. Do not spam extraneous tags in an attempt to attract more attention to your question. That kind of behavior does not go over well with the community.

Comment: Hey! It was not in my intention to spam. I'm new to Javascript and thought they were the same thing. @MarsAtomic

Answer (score 0):

Your expression in the if statement is backwards. It should be `age >= 14`

```js
function buy() {

  let name = prompt("What is your name?");

  let age = prompt("How old are you?");

  if (age >= 14) {

    alert("Hey, " + name + "!  Have fun buying on our site! ");

  } else {

    alert("Sorry, " + name + "... You are too young to buy on our website. You might have to ask your parents. ");

  }

}

let buyButton = document.querySelector(".buy-button");

buyButton.addEventListener("click", buy);
```

```html
<button class="buy-button">Buy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you get from `prompt` is `string` so it is needed to parse the string `age` value into `number` page value for comparison.

```js
function buy() {
  let name = prompt("What is your name?");
  let age = prompt("How old are you?");
  
  age = parseInt(age); // This is the part you should add.
  if (age <= 14) {
    alert("Hey, " + name + "!  Have fun buying on our site! ");
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, " + name + "... You are too young to buy on our website. You might have to ask your parents. ");
  }
}

let buyButton = document.querySelector(".buy-button");
buyButton.addEventListener("click", buy);
```

```html
<button class="buy-button">Buy Button</button>
```